# objective C enable UIScrollView scroll while UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I added a `-(void) detectTouch: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) event` for `UIScrollView` and detecting the angle on which user is moving his finger. My task is to scroll the `UIScrollView` horizontally only when user is moving the finger between 0 - 30 degrees (just to make sure he is drawing a horizontal straight line) otherwise I have to disable the `UIScrollView` scroll.

I am detecting the angle by drawing a triangle using the touch starting point and ending point.

**Problem:** I enabled the `UIScrollView` scroll when the angle is < 30 degrees but this is not working on the first time. Although I enabled scroll using `scrollEnabled = YES` it is working only when user is stopped touching the screen (taking the finger from the screen).

The following code I used to

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self PanGesture:self.view callBack:@selector(detectTouch:) delegate:self];
    incrementer = 0;    
}

-(void) detectTouch: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) event{
    // Calculating point A on gesture starts
    if(event.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        pointA.x = fabs([event translationInView:event.view].x);
        pointA.y = fabs([event translationInView:event.view].y);

        NSLog(@"A: %f, %f", pointA.x, pointA.y);
    }

    incrementer += 1;

    // Start calculating Point B, Point C on calling this function 3 times
    if(incrementer >= 3){

        // Calculating point C
        pointC.x = fabs([event translationInView:event.view].x);
        pointC.y = fabs([event translationInView:event.view].y);

        NSLog(@"C: %f, %f", pointC.x, pointC.y);

        // calculate pointB using A, C
        pointB.x = fabs(pointC.x);
        pointB.y = fabs(pointA.y);

        NSLog(@"B: %f, %f", pointB.x, pointB.y);

        float X = pointB.x - pointA.x;
        float Y = pointC.y - pointB.y;
        float angle = (atan(fabs(Y) / fabs(X)) * 180 / M_PI);

        if(angle > 30){
            // This disable is not working on while user is moving the finger
            self.myScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            NSLog(@"UIScroll Disabled");
        }else{
            // This enable is not working on while user is moving the finger
            self.myScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            NSLog(@"UIScroll Enabled");
        }

        incrementer = 0;
    }
}
```

How can I enable `UIScrollView` scroll while user is moving the touch?

Comment: where exactly you are creating your pan gesture recognizer??i dont see anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Since UIScrollView seems to accept scrolling only with a new touch after you set .scrollEnabled to YES, I would do the following:

- set .scrollEnabled to NO
- Track the touch (e. g. with touchesMoved::)
- check whether you 30 degrees condition is met
- use the movement to adjust UIScrollView.contentOffset